# Symfony2 - Add a required checkbox to an Image Form Field

Tags: forms, symfony, upload

I need the form to display a checkbox field, when the user selected an image for the upload in an image Form Field and make this required.

The User has to confirm, that he claims the rights on that picture.

I've already tried to make a custom Validator, but i think this won't work for that scenario.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well, 2 solutions:

- you do this via html with an . The user have to check this after uploading his picture. If you don't checked the box, it won't submit the form.
- With a boolean in your entity, you set it to required=true and you will display it like any other field. But, the result in the database will always be true.. ( useless )